# Booting Windows from VROC RAID

Tags: boot, raid, windows-server-2019

I installed Windows (tried server 2019 as well as 2016) on a Intel VROC RAID0 Raid (VROC seems to be the only RAID option my SuperMicro X11Dai-N offers). During installation, I had to load the VROC drivers, otherwise the setup would not have seen the hard disk.

Now after successful setup, the windows boot-manager is loaded (meaning that the UEFI obviously can access the Raid), but after that, windows doesn't boot and gives me an INACCESSIBLE BOOT DEVICE blue-screen.

I assume that´s because the windows boot-manager doesn't have the VROC drivers to access the RAID disk?

How can I install drivers in the boot-manager so that it can access the raid?